# R svydesign loop

Tags: r

Using R, I want to generate a table that summarizes the design effect for each evaluation unit in a dataset.

I am able to calculate the design effect for one evaluation unit at a time, but am wondering how to do this for the entire dataset at once.

This is what my code currently looks like.

```
design<- svydesign(id=~cluster+hh, fpc=~fpc1+fpc2, data=data, pps="brewer")

mysvymean <- svymean(~tt_pos, design, deff = TRUE)

deff(mysvymean)
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.